# how to find and change all the default figure setting in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure

This [tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/default-property-values.html) explains how to change certain default settings of Matlab figures, but what about the properties not listed there? For example, if I want to change the font size of the x-axis label and make the y-axis label in Latex style, whats the name for these properties? (what's the xxx in defaultxxx)

In other words, I'm looking for something similar to [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) matplotlib stylesheet (but for Matlab) where I can easily find the names of the properties I'm looking for so I can just change the values easily.

Comment: If you have something specific in mind, we could help to write the script to set it ;)

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB has a built-in figure editor, so you can do pretty much anything there. When you plot something, in the figure, go to View > Property editor and you try different things.

If you want to do it manually, the problem is that there is not just one object in the plot figure. You can generally look at the options for [figures](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html), [axes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html), [plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) and [surface](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surface.html). However, it it possible that you will have to look further for some more specific types of figures. Useful things can be found [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/), that are not in the official MATLAB documentation, but you must usually search a lot.

I was looking at the link you provided for matplotlib and decided to do something similar as an example of working with MATLAB plots. The following code:

```
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
y = sin(x);

% Plot a sinus curve, make the data depicted with red line and red filled dots
plot(x, y, 'r-o','MarkerFaceColor','r')

set(gca, ...                  % Get current axes
    'Color','k', ...          % Set plot background color to black
    'XColor',[1 1 1], ...     % Set color of x axis to white
    'YColor',[1 1 1], ...     % Set color of y axis to white
    'GridColor',[1 1 1], ...  % Set color of grid to white
    'GridLineStyle','--', ... % Set the grid to be dashed
    'YTick',-1:0.25:1)        % Set Y axis ticks from -1 to 1 with step 0.25
set(gcf,'Color','k')          % Set background of the current figure to black
xlabel('Some x axis / Units') % Set X axis label
ylabel('Some y axis / Units') % Set Y axis label
grid on                       % Make the grid shown
```

And the result should look like this:
[image]

By the way, you can use some basic LaTeX notation in MATLAB without changing anything. Try writing something like

```
xlabel('\rho_{0} / kg m^{-3}')
```